# Segment control iOS 7 separator delete between images

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode5

My question is connected with iOS7 adaptation. Actually, I use `UISegmentControl` and every element represents a `UIImage`. Moreover, there are no problem on iOS6, but after some period of time when I started to use XCode5 and iOS7, I have a little problem. To make a long story short, there is a distance between images. And my question is the following: how to delete this empty place between images?

[image: problem description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a divider image for each possibility of states in your segmentedControl

```
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage: forLeftSegmentState: rightSegmentState: barMetrics:]
```

Sine you have 3 segments there are 5 Left Right combinations:

1. selected - normal
2. normal - selected
3. normal - normal
4. highlighted - selected
5. selected - highlighted